# How can I get next-env.d.ts for Intellisense without NextJS using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, next.js, intellisense

According to the [NextJS docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript#existing-projects), in order to get object types you need to use TypeScript by creating a `tsconfig.json` file, and it automagically creates `next-env.d.ts`.

Unfortunately, I'm not in a work environment where I can introduce a TypeScript requirement into the developer job description. But I liberally sprinkle my files with JSDocs, to take advantage of Intellisense.

Does anyone have a way of generating `next-env.d.ts` without forcing NextJS into TypeScript compilation?

Comment: Why do you need the `next-env.d.ts` file? It's just patching types for TypeScript. If you don't use TypeScript you don't need it.

Comment: VSCode uses TypeScript internally to provide Intellisense. Without the declarations, it can't provide any suggestions specific to NextJS.

Comment: Does the tripple slash directive not work? `/// <reference path="index.d.ts"/>
Because the content of the `next-env.d.ts` is not overwhelming: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/create-next-app/templates/typescript/next-env.d.ts